# Taylor polynomial estimation

Tags: taylor-expansion

Estimate the following expression using second order Taylor polynomial:
$$\ln ({1.04^{0.25}} + {0.98^{0.2}} - 1)$$

edit: $\ln(1.04^{0.25}+0.98^{0.2}-1)$

I'm going crazy, why it doesn't show the formula written in Mathtype?!

Tried defining $$f(x,y) = \ln(1+(x^{0.25}+y^{0.2}-1))$$ and using taylor for $\ln(1+x)$ however it is too complicated to calculate by hand and that is not the author intention

Comment: Consider $$f(x) = \ln \bigl( (1 + 4x)^{1/4} + (1 - 2x)^{1/5} - 1\bigr).$$ Use the Taylor expansion of $(1 + y)^{\alpha}$ as well as that of $\ln (1 + z)$.

Answer (score 0):

Break down the components first using the series expansion
$$
(x+1)^a \approx 1+a x + \frac{1}{2} (a-1) a x^2 + \dots
$$

---

$$
\color{blue}{1.04^{0.25}} = \left( 1 + \delta \right)^{0.25} \approx 1+ 0.25 \delta-0.09375 \delta ^2
$$
For $\delta = 0.04$, 
$$
1+ 0.25 \delta-0.09375 \delta ^2 = \color{blue}{1.00985}
$$
For the next term $\delta = 0.02$, and 
$$
\color{red}{0.98^{0.2} \approx 1.00397}
$$
The equation is now
$$
 \ln \left( \color{blue}{1.04^{0.25}} + \color{red}{0.98^{0.2}} - 1 \right) \approx 
 \ln \left( 1.01382 \right)
$$

---

Note
$$
 \ln x \approx x-\frac{x^2}{2} + \dots
$$
and the second order answer is
$$
\boxed{
 \ln x \approx x-\frac{x^2}{2} \approx 0.0137245
}
$$

---

Full precision answer
$$
\ln \left(1.04^{0.25}+0.98^{0.2}-1\right) = 0.0058041404311517\dots
$$